# Table to check Transaction Code Authorization

Tags: authorization, abap

I am doing Internet Scenario for Plant Maintenance(PM) module. In that I have to check whether the user is having authorization for the Tcode or not. Authorization for PM module's Tcode is I_TCODE, but I could not find the exact table which relates Authorization to user. Did anyone know about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want to check a table?  Shouldn't the FM AUTHORITY_CHECK_TCODE do what you need?

Comment: I have to check whether user has authorization for Tcode or not. If they have authorization, then when they are login they can view the tcodes in right side tree structure.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reports to check this - you can find them using the transaction SUIM. Don't do it manually - there are various ways that users can be assigned permissions (direct profile assignment, profile assignment via single role, collective roles that contain single roles, ...). You probably don't want to deal with that kind of boring complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to perform authorization checks in SAP: [authorization checks at help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04s/helpdata/en/52/67129f439b11d1896f0000e8322d00/frameset.htm)

Answer (score 0):

By joining the Database tables **AGR_USERS** & **AGR_1251**, we can get the Tcodes which are authorized to user.